# Publishing a C# console application as an Azure web job

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I've got a console application, with logging, scheduling, etc., running on a VM. It works with Entity Framework, Azure SQL Server, Azure blob storage and a bunch of external APIs.

I'd like to turn it into a service.

I understand that this can be done with worker roles, but looking at various tutorials for worker roles, it seems like it would be a ton of work to rewrite the whole thing.

If I just publish it as a web job, will this be secure, assuming I don't have any exposed endpoints? I need to make sure that nobody outside our active directory can access it.

Is there a way that I can create a dummy app service which will have no endpoints and publish it there?

Comment: Yes, if it does not expose any endpoints no one can acces it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I just publish it as a web job, will this be secure, assuming I don't have any exposed endpoints? I need to make sure that nobody outside our active directory can access it.

As Peter Bons said, if it does not expose an API or endpoint, nobody can access it.

> Is there a way that I can create a dummy app service which will have no endpoints and publish it there?

Normally we run WebJobs in a Azure App Service web app, and that Azure App Service web app can be accessed/browsed via URL. If you want to prevent users from browsing to that Azure App Service web app, you can add a rewrite rule to site’s web.config to [block web access](http://ruslany.net/2014/04/azure-web-sites-block-web-access-to-non-production-deployment-slots/).

```
<rule name="Block unauthorized traffic to staging sites" stopProcessing="true">  
<match url=".*" />  
<conditions>  
<!-- Enter your site host name here as the pattern-->  
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^sitehostname\." />  
<!-- Enter your white listed IP addresses -->  
<add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="123\.123\.123\.1" negate="true"/>  
<!-- Add the white listed IP addresses with a new condition as seen below -->  
<!-- <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="123\.123\.123\.2" negate="true"/> -->  
</conditions>  
<action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden"  
statusDescription="Site is not accessible" />  
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

what exactly your exe is? will someone invoke it and scheduled to run on a regular intervals?
we have couple of options here, if the processing logic is not a complex one you can go for [Azure functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) which uses [WebJobs SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk) itself but doesn't require an [App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/) to be configured for it. 
or you can go for [Azure Scheduler](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/) which can take your executable and run at a scheduled intervals.